# Put the combinations matrix of many rows in a column of a dataframe, then split it

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this (I simplify):

```
df <- data.frame(rbind(c(1, "dog", "cat", "rabbit"), c(2, "apple", "peach", "cucumber")))
colnames(df) <- c("ID", "V1", "V2", "V3")

##   ID    V1    V2       V3
## 1  1   dog   cat   rabbit
## 2  2 apple peach cucumber
```

I would like to create a column containing all possible combinations of variables V1:V3 two by two (order doesn't matter), but keeping a link with the original ID. So something like this.

```
##    ID  bigrams
## 1   1    dog cat
## 2   1    cat rabbit
## 3   1    dog rabbit
## 4   2    apple peach
## 5   2    apple cucumber
## 6   2    peach cucumber
```

My idea: use `combn()`, `mutate()` and `separate_row()`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
mutate(bigrams=paste(unlist(t(combn(df[,2:4],2))), collapse="-")) %>% 
separate_rows(bigrams, sep="-") %>% 
select(ID,bigrams)
```

The result is not what I expected... I guess that concatenating a matrix (the result of `combine()`) is not as easy as that.

I have two questions about this: 1) how to debug this code? 2) Is this a good way to do this kind of thing? I'm new on R but I’ve an Open Refine background, so concatenate-split multivalued cells make a lot of sense for me. But is this also the right method with R?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), `melt` it to 'long' format, grouped by 'ID', get the `combn` of 'value' and `paste` it together

```
library(data.table)
dM <- melt(setDT(df), id.var = "ID")[, combn(value, 2, FUN = paste, collapse=' '), ID]
setnames(dM, 2, 'bigrams')[]
#   ID        bigrams
#1:  1        dog cat
#2:  1     dog rabbit
#3:  1     cat rabbit
#4:  2    apple peach
#5:  2 apple cucumber
#6:  2 peach cucumber
```

Comment: Woh! 0_0 I knew that data.table is a powerful package, but it always seemed complicated for me and especially dedicated for big dataframes. I will try to learn it to understand these two lines. Thanks a lot, @Akrun! I will wait a bit, but I do not see how to make it shorter.

Comment: Translation in the tidyverse would be: `df %>% gather("variable", "value", -ID) %>% group_by(ID) %>% transmute(bigrams = combn(value, 2, paste, collapse = " ")) %>% ungroup()`. No added value here, so I won't make it a separate answer

Comment: Thanks, Aurèle ! For now, I feel more comfortable with the tidyverse.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend @akrun's "`melt` first" approach, but just for fun, here are more ways to do it:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate_all(as.character) %>% 
  transmute(ID = ID, bigrams = pmap(
    list(V1, V2, V3), 
    function(a, b, c) combn(c(a, b, c), 2, paste, collapse = " ")
  ))
#   ID                                     bigrams
# 1  1             dog cat, dog rabbit, cat rabbit
# 2  2 apple peach, apple cucumber, peach cucumber
```

(`mutate_all(as.character)` just because you gave us factors, and factor to character conversion can be surprising).

```
df %>% 
  mutate_all(as.character) %>%
  nest(-ID) %>% 
  mutate(bigrams = map(data, combn, 2, paste, collapse = " ")) %>%
  unnest(data) %>% 
  as.data.frame()
#   ID                                     bigrams    V1    V2       V3
# 1  1             dog cat, dog rabbit, cat rabbit   dog   cat   rabbit
# 2  2 apple peach, apple cucumber, peach cucumber apple peach cucumber
```

(`as.data.frame()` just for a prettier printing)

Comment: Very interesting solution, which will undoubtedly reserve me in other contexts. I will examine it in detail. Now that I've seen the solutions in `data.table` and` tidyverse`, I will choose, as you suggest, the first answer, which is faster and shorter. Thank you very much !